# How to show different widgets on different pages in a user friendly way

Tags: widgets, pages, sidebar

I'm looking for a plugin to let users choose which widgets appear on individual pages.

There's some solutions out there, none of which that I've found are truly easy for a non-technical user. I've tried

- **[Woo Themes Sidebar manager](http://www.woothemes.com/videos/the-sidebar-manager-overview/)** -  Great
  functionality, but a user would need a lot of training to understand
  templates, sidebars and widgets - quite confusing.
- Plugins like **Widget context** and **Widget logic**, both of
  which, in my opinion are difficult for an average user.

I have seen a good-looking solution which uses the Genesis Framework ([simple sidebars](http://www.studiopress.com/plugins/simple-sidebars)) - this has the right approach. The user can choose the widget from *within* the page editor. To me, that's the important point.

So, does anyone know any plugins (not using Genesis) which allow the same in-page choosing of sidebars?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own sidebar if you want.

add the following to your `functions.php`

```
 register_sidebar(array('name'=>'Sidebar ',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="widget">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<p>',
    'after_title' => '</p>',
));
```

and you can use this widget by using the following code

```
<?php dynamic_sidebar('sidebar')?>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try [Display Widgets](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/display-widgets/). It's what i use most of the time, and it's pretty simple to use from the Widgets settings. It might also be possible to tweak it to function as a meta box.

Comment: Agreed, I've used it and it **is** very good and quite easy to use (lots of scrolling though) but as sites grow and so do the number of custom sidebars, the widgets page gets hard to manage. Also for the user it's hard to see which widgets are on which page. 

I'd really like to find a solution which appears on the edit page/post screen.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Widget Context](http://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-context/) to achieve this. It's quite [flexible](http://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-context/screenshots/), covers almost every logic you would need to display/hide a widget and in case it's not there lets you create custom rules like a specific url where you would like to display / hide your widget.

Not to mention it's been around for a long time and is well maintained.

Answer (score 0):

You can use code to control where your widget displays by adding a conditional tag to the code which calls your sidebar in your template file:

```
<?php if ( is_page('007') && is_active_sidebar( 'your-sidebar' ) ) : ?>
<div class="your-sidebar">
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'your-sidebar' ); ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Another way to call your widget is to use code like this directly in a template file or from your functions file:

```
add_action( 'loop_start', 'conditional_sidebar' );

function conditional_sidebar() {

if ( is_page('007') && is_active_sidebar( 'your-sidebar' ) ) {

dynamic_sidebar( 'your-sidebar', array(
'before' => '<div class="your-sidebar widget-area">',
'after'  => '</div>',
) );

    }
}
```

Note: This code will only work if you have also registered a sidebar in your functions file.

```
register_sidebar( array(
'name'         => __( 'Your Sidebar' ),
'id'           => 'your-sidebar',
'description'  => __( 'Only displays on page with I.D 007' )
) );
```